# Call to Async WebClient method stalling

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have the following piece of code:

```
public ActionResult DraftScores()
    {
// other code

var json = "";

var fixturesUrl = "someURL";


using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.Headers.Add("X-Auth-Token", "7d594032xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    json = wc.DownloadString(fixturesUrl);
}

var fixtureList = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<FixtureList>(json);

model.Matches = fixtureList.matches;

        return View(model);
    }
```

I tried to extract this into it's own Async method:

```
    private async Task<List<Match>> GetFixturesAsync()
    {
        var json = "";

        var fixturesUrl = "someURL";

        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            wc.Headers.Add("X-Auth-Token", "7d594032xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
            json =  await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(fixturesUrl);
        }

        var fixtureList = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<FixtureList>(json);

        return fixtureList.matches;
    }
```

calling code:

```
public ActionResult DraftScores()
    {

//other code

var fixtures = GetFixturesAsync();

   //other code

    model.Matches = fixtures.Result;

        return View(model);
    }
```

In the original code the call to ***DownloadString*** executes in about 200ms.
However the call to ***DownloadStringTaskAsync*** is still running after several seconds. Is there something wrong with the way that I have written the method?

Comment: How are you calling `GetFixturesAsync`? When using async, you must make sure that the whole call chain is async. If you're calling `GetFixturesAsync().Result` instead of `await GetFixturesAsync()`, it can explain the behavior you're seeing

Comment: I edited the question to include the call and usage code - i am using .Result so I'll have a look at that thanks

Comment: Show the _complete_ codepath. async/await must form a chain.

Comment: You are [blocking on async code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). Use `await`, not `.Result`.

Comment: I've included the full code path. Are you saying that the DraftScores method itself has to be marked as async?

Comment: Yes, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

To do async I/O properly, you need an unbroken await chain from your Controller to the DownloadStringTaskAsync() call.

Step 1, make the Action async.
Step 2, await the async call.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> DraftScores()
{
   ...
   List<Match> result = await GetFixturesAsync();
   ...
}
```

Always avoid `async void`, `.Result` and `.Wait()`

Comment: If you put the await on the method call does that not basically stop the code from moving on? Would it not make more sense to put the await on the point at which the result variable is actually used?

Comment: The result is a Task, it does not really matter when (where) you await it.